# Cell Contains Formula NOT blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a row with three cell each one contains formula and all formula result is blank, my question how can i use if formula to have the following result?
- in case all 3 cell blank  ---> (0) 
in case one or two cell have value (not blank) ---> (33)

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A1:C1)>0),33,0)
```

Comment: @Nawaf as the person who posted the question, only you can close it by select the answer that you used as the correct one.  You do this by clicking the check mark by the answer that you used.

Answer (score 0):

### Not 0 or Not ""?

- A blank cell is a cell that doesn't contain anything. Since there is
  a formula in those cells, you are probably asking if the value is `0`
  or `""`. Maybe both.

**If you mean blank as in value `0`:**

If you will treat an error value as a value then use the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1=0,B1=0,C1=0),0,33),33)
```

Otherwise use the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1=0,B1=0,C1=0),0,33),0)
```

or e.g.

```
=IFERROR(IF(SUM(A1:C1)=0,0,33),0)
```

**If you mean blank as in value `""`:**

If you will treat an error value as a value then use the following

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1="",B1="",C1=""),0,33),33)
```

Otherwise use the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1="",B1="",C1=""),0,33),0)
```

or e.g.

```
=IFERROR(IF(TEXTJOIN("",,A1:C1)="",0,33),0)
```

There are many other solutions